# How to deal with this situation (path changes) in Nginx?

Tags: nginx

If I write the config like this:

```
location: /a {
    root    /home/files/b/
}
```

and I request `http://example.com/a/1.jpg`, Nginx would consider that I am requesting `/home/files/b/a/1.jpg`, but I want Nginx to get `/home/files/b/1.jpg` instead.

How to resolve this issue?

P.S. Consider that the paths `/a`, `/b`, and their structure of sub folders are unchangeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use alias instead of root (http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#alias)

```
location: /a { alias /home/files/b/ }
```